# ora-29540 class does not exist

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, oracle19c

[image]

Hi eveyone,

I have a function called tax_apiconfig which is created from java source

But when I run the function, I get the attached image error:

Ora-29450 class ir/gov/tax/tpis/sdk/transfer/config/ApiConfig does not exist

Also, the Java source is valid and exists in the ALL_OBJECTS table.

Could someone help me?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the details of how you loaded the class into the database (i.e. `CREATE JAVA SOURCE` or the `loadjava` utility); the `CREATE FUNCTION` statement for `tax_apiconfig`; and details of the code you are using to call that function. Check that everything is owned by the same user or that the users are `GRANT`ed permissions to access the source/function if they are not in the same user.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Java source version and Oracle's jdk version do not match

```
SELECT dbms_java.get_jdk_version() FROM dual;
```